# Is the Filmography tag now obsolete?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

With our ongoing efforts and struggle to keep the questions being asked on the Movies SE site objective I was wondering if the [tag Filmography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/filmography/info) is now obsolete or simply being misused.

Out of the 4 questions [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filmography), [one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51591/lou-diamond-phillips-first-movie) is already closed for being an identification question. Out of the remaining 3, [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39562/bu%C3%B1uels-movies-in-languages-other-than-spanish-or-french) seems to err towards a list question. Whereas the other 2 seem to be seeking recommendations, which again is considered [off-topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Going forward, what should be our course for this tag and the associated questions?

Comment: One of the questions didn't even deserve the tag so I removed it (it didn't actually ask for a recommendation either, but that's beside the point of this meta).

Answer (score 5):

My initial thought is

### Keep it

Not that we have any questions on the subject but something like....

> What were the common influences/theme on the filmography of [insert actor/director here]

would, I think, be the intention of the tag *as it stands*.

The existing questions are locked or, at the very least, not easily deletable but 4 out of nearly 16,000 is an acceptable ratio to me.

Comment: Absolutely! That ratio is more than acceptable. My question isn't so much about what to do with the questions, rather what to do with the tag? One option would be to indicate pretty clearly the intention and right usage of the tag. The questions themselves can be acted upon according to the site's on-topic rules and will prove to be good historical content to point to.

Comment: Indeed...a quick edit of the tag wiki might be in order.

Comment: Edited the tag excerpt outlining correct usage of the tag and re-iterating our on-topic policy.